# Find an object with a matching key in a list of objects

Tags: python, django

I have code that looks like this (.customers refers to a list of Django models named Customer):

```
return bundle.request.user.id in bundle.obj.customers.all()
```

This doesn't work because it's checking an id against a list of Customer objects. I want something that offers similar optimized evaluation to Django's all() but will return true if one of the customers in the list has a matching id. Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What does your `Customer` model look like? Does it have a foreign key to `User`?

Comment: a customer is a user... sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return bundle.obj.customers.filter(id=bundle.request.user.id).exists()`

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) on the `exists` method.

Answer (score 0):

With as few modifications as possible:

```
return bundle.request.user.id in {x.id for x in bundle.obj.customers.all()}
```

or if `all()` is not yet evaluated, and indexes are present in db, following query will be faster

```
return bundle.obj.customers.filter(id = bundle.request.user.id).exists()
```